# sending a file to slimframework from nodejs server

Tags: php, node.js, file-upload, request

i want to sent a file from my server to my rest api on another server, but for some reason it is not getting the data i sent..

rest api php using slim framework:

```
    $app->post
(
    '/api/upload',
    function () use ($app)
    {
        $logs = '/home/logs';
        //error_log(print_r($_FILES, 1), 3, $logs . '/export16.log');
        try
        {
            $data = file_get_contents('php://input'); // EMPTY!!!!
            error_log(print_r(count($data), 1), 3, $logs . '/export16.log');
        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
            error_log(print_r($data, 1), 3, $logs . '/export16err.log');
        }
    }
);
```

nodejs using request module:

```
        fs.createReadStream('myfile.zip')
    .pipe
    (
        request.post
        (
            UPLOAD_URL,

            function (error, response, body)
            {
                //console.log(response);
                if (!error && response.statusCode == 200)
                {
                    //console.log(repons);
                }
            }
        )
    );
```

also tried with this code: using form-data module as explained in the docs

```
    var r = request.post(UPLOAD_URL, function optionalCallback (err, httpResponse, body) {
  if (err) {
    return console.error('upload failed:', err);
  }
  console.log(httpResponse);
  console.log('Upload successful!  Server responded with:', body);
})
var form = r.form();

form.append('my_file', fs.createReadStream('file.zip') );
```

they both don't work and i get not data in my php:input,
i see the header content type: application/zip is set, but nothing else, somethign is missing maybe?

```
     _header: 'POST /api/upload HTTP/1.1\r\nhost: xyz.com\r\ncontent-type: a
pplication/zip\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nTransfer-Encoding: chunked\r\n\r\n',
```

any ideas what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out i had to set the content length :)